# How to route audio input through iPhone microphone and audio output through bluetooth earphones in iOS 14?

Tags: ios, audio, ear-phones

The earphones I have support Bluetooth 4.1 and as a result, audio quality through them during phone calls is pretty sub-standard. This is because the Bluetooth 4.1 standard cannot accommodate both output and input audio through the limited bandwidth. As a result, iPhones default to a lower quality codec during phone calls while using Bluetooth 4.1 earphones. But otherwise while listening to music the audio quality is very good.

Is it possible to route the output through my Bluetooth earphones while simultaneously routing input audio through the in-built microphone during a phone call on iOS 14? If it helps, I have a pair of JBL Tune 205BT. Is there any other way to enjoy high quality audio during phone calls on these earphones?

Comment: Duplicate - https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/91761/routing-bluetooth-audio-in-and-out-of-headphone-mic-jack-on-iphone and https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/91761/routing-bluetooth-audio-in-and-out-of-headphone-mic-jack-on-iphone As far as I know, no - on ios, both audio input and output must be on the same route. It may be possible with specific apps but not with built-in ios core apps like the Phone app.